# Regex to extract size in millimeters from a string

Tags: python, regex

I want to use regex in Python to obtain the three following types of product dimensions from a string (notice the spaces).

1. `"20x20mm"`
2. `"20 x 20 mm"`
3. `"20x20 mm"`

These are all contained in the middle of strings, representing sizes or products. 
I figured I could find these product dimensions by using Regex to find the `'x'` or `'mm'`, as these are the constant strings. I would like to obtain an output that just gives me the product dimensions.

Could anyone help me out with this?

An example string would be this:

```
"XY SmallProduct with BIZ/10351, transparent, 75x150mm, Inh. 12"
```

Comment: Please show us your failed regex creation. You've made an attempt to come up with a regex yourself, yes?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I indeed made a regex myself, which was only capable to detect the first format:
`re.sub('[^a-zA-Züäö0-9()ß-]',' ', str(text))`
(I included German characters as I had to deal with those as well in some strings)

Comment: I used a split afterwards, so that the size would be detected. Thus, was kind of a workaround, not efficient at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex would do the trick:

```
([0-9]+) ?x ?([0-9]+) ?mm
```

The first number is in the first capture group, second number in the second capture group.

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/s3D7Dp/2)